# Reduce font size

Tags: css

I need your assistance regarding my problem. In fact, I've tried to change the slider's font size on my website : http://compil2rai.com/ on the style.css file, but the changes are not taken in account. Any help ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhKlL.jpg

Comment: at which line of `style.css` have you tried to change this ?

Comment: 193
.featured-text h2,
.featured-text h2 a {
 font-size: 58px;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a WordPress question, but add the following in your stylesheet:

```
.featured-text h2, .featured-text h2 a {
    font-size: 24px !important; /* set font size */
}
```

In the future, simply *Inspect Element* to find which class or tag to style.

Comment: I added this code in my style.css, but apprently the font still big
Here is the code:

.featured-text h2, .featured-text h2 a {
    font-size: 58px;

Comment: you don't have edited the good file. you must edit this one which is not modified for 5 days : http://compil2rai.com/wp-content/themes/braxton/style.css

Comment: Make sure that you are not seeing a cached page. Save new CSS, ppen a private browser (incognito) and then refresh. Add the following: .featured-text h2, .featured-text h2 a {font-size: 58px !important;}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added your line using Custom CSS Manager plugin, the result is just awesome.